# How to limit the maximum missing gap of interpolated values

Tags: interpolation, stata

When interpolating or extrapolating (using `ipolate` with or without `epolate`) missing values, is it possible either to limit in advance the missing gap size to be interpolated (or extrapolated), or to figure the gap size post hoc?

Really what I want is to limit the maximum consecutive interpolations (my data is yearly) to three years.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always calculate the length of spells and then use `ipolate` only conditionally. Here I use `tsspell` from SSC to calculate such lengths introduced artificially:

```
webuse grunfeld, clear 
set seed 2803 
replace invest = . if runiform() < 0.2 
tsset company year 
* need previous -ssc install tsspell- to run this 
tsspell , cond(missing(invest)) 
egen length = max(_seq), by(company _spell) 
tab length 
list company year invest if length >= 3, sepby(company _spell)

     +-------------------------+
     | company   year   invest |
     |-------------------------|
 13. |       1   1947        . |
 14. |       1   1948        . |
 15. |       1   1949        . |
     |-------------------------|
 41. |       3   1935        . |
 42. |       3   1936        . |
 43. |       3   1937        . |
     +-------------------------+

ipolate invest year if length <= 2, by(company) epolate
```